# How to add select all checkbox in Django admin panel to all editable column?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I searched in the last day for information about how to add a select/deselect all checkbox into my Django admin panel but I didn't find the solution.
I like to have these checkbox for all the columns not just for the first (in this case the user model). I like to manage all the objects with one checkbox click but it is also important to save the choice and if I come back to this site it should show the condition I saved before.
I attached an image about what I like to do.[image]

Comment: You can edit tabular.html